pgloader with COPY option with nulls as /N fails
Attempting to use pgloader and the file has some rows with \N which need to rendered as NULL.
This is what i have but it fails?
LOAD COPY
FROM '/mnt/adhoc/data.cpy'
INTO postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?data_tab
WITH
NULL AS '\N'

Fails with:
At

  WITH
  NULL AS '\N'

       ^ (Line 5, Column 5, Position 160)

In context OPTION-NULL:

While parsing DOUBLE-QUOTED-STRING. Expected:

     the character " (QUOTATION_MARK)

While parsing SINGLE-QUOTED-STRING. Expected:

     the character ' (APOSTROPHE)

While parsing IGNORE-WHITESPACE. Expected:

     the character Tab
  or the character Newline
  or the character Return
  or the character Space
  or the string "--"
  or the string "/*"

Expecting all references of \N in the file to be treated as NULL
